# Java Clear Screen

Tags: java, applet, terminate

I'm looking for a specific code that if a button is clicked the whole applet will clear screen and a new interfaces like labels, images, buttons will appear, is it possible? or if not are there any methods on terminating an applet then run a different applet at the same time when a button was pressed?

Comment: Hide(remove) all the component from the main container(panel), then change the panel back ground panel and start to load something new and so on...

Comment: Take a look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: What a button is an input field?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% if this is what you're asking, but I'll try and help with it anyway:

You may want to do some research into [JPanels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) and the setViewport() method, this way, you can add all the items you want.

e.g. Say you had 2 JPanels, a and b, you can put a load of buttons and labels and whatever you want on one JPanel and then a load more onto the other, then you can simply switch between them using setViewport(a); or setViewort(b);

It's really simple and useful if you don't want to make a new JFrame pop- up for seperate parts of your program.